# newman command can not parse the json file in jenkins

Tags: json, jenkins, postman

I am trying to make automation in API testing.
For that I used newman.

It is working in my shell.
But when I am trying to put it in jenkins. It doesn't work.
I am using below command for run the my test case in jenkins

```
newman -c /home/soham/Desktop/api.json --insecure
```

Jenkins gives below error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/api_automation/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4223675241512864410.sh
+ newman -c /home/soham/Desktop/api.json --insecure
[31mThe collection file /home/soham/Desktop/api.json could not be parsed.
[39mBuild step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I solved this issue. it's a permission issue. I just changed my  file permission 400 to 644 and It's works fine.